# JavaFx: Method selectAll() just works by focus with keyboard

Tags: javafx-2, javafx

i use selectionAll() to select the whole text in my textfield but it just works when the focus comes from keyboard (like Tab).

If i click with my mouse in the textfield, it selects the text just for a very short moment. But it has to work like with the focus which comes from the keyboard.

```java
flaschenPreis.focusedProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>() {
    public void changed(ObservableValue ov, Boolean t, Boolean t1) {

        if ( flaschenPreis.isFocused() && !flaschenPreis.getText().isEmpty()) {
            flaschenPreis.selectAll();
        }              
    }
});


literPreis.focusedProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener() {
    public void changed(ObservableValue ov, Object t, Object t1) {

        if (literPreis.isFocused() && !literPreis.getText().isEmpty()) {
            literPreis.selectAll();
        }
    }
});
```

flaschenPreis und literPreis are my textfields

Comment: it looks like a bug ,please report here http://javafx-jira.kenai.com/secure/Dashboard.jspa

Answer (score 23):

This trick will help you :

```java
final TextField tf = new TextField("Text");
tf.focusedProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>() {
    @Override
    public void changed(ObservableValue ov, Boolean t, Boolean t1) {

        Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (tf.isFocused() && !tf.getText().isEmpty()) {
                    tf.selectAll();
                }
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Wow! It works!! Awesome!!! This part is so important for the programm im working on. Thank you so much!! I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Sonja, did you file an issue about that?

Comment: We're over 5 years and a few Java(FX) releases further, but the problem seems to be still in (using Java 8u172 and related JavaFX)...  Has the issue been filed?

Comment: Nice. `Platform.runLater()` solved the problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

```java
PathField.focusedProperty().addListener((obs, wasFocused, isNowFocused) -> {
    if (isNowFocused) {
        Platform.runLater(() -> PathField.selectAll());
    }
});
```